# Null pointer detection in tcc

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, clang, tcc

I created a very simple linked list and noticed a difference in output for `tcc filename.c` vs `tcc filename.c -run` for my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct llist {
    struct llist *next;
    struct llist *last;
    struct llist *first;
    int value;
    int item;
    int *length;
};

struct llist *newList(int v){

    struct llist *l1 = malloc(sizeof(struct llist)); 
    l1 -> length = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *l1 -> length = 1;

    l1 -> value = v;    
    l1 -> item = 0;    
    l1 -> first = l1;

    return l1;
}

struct llist *appendList(struct llist *l1, int v){

    struct llist *l2 = malloc(sizeof(struct llist));

    l2 -> value = v;
    l2 -> last = l1;
    l2 -> first = l1 -> first;
    l2 -> length = l1 -> length; 
    *l2 -> length += 1; 
    l2 -> item = l1 -> item + 1;

    l1 -> next = l2;

    return l2;    
};

int main(){
    struct llist *list = newList(4);
    list = appendList(list, 6);
    list = appendList(list, 8);
    list = appendList(list, 10);

    list = list -> first;

    int end = 0;
    while(end==0){

        printf("VAL: %d\n", list -> value);

        if(list -> next == NULL){
            printf("END\n");
            end = 1;
        }else{

            list = list -> next;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

For compiling with `tcc filename.c` and then running it produces the output I expected:

```
VAL: 4
VAL: 6
VAL: 8
VAL: 10
END
```

It's also the output I get in GCC and clang.

When I use `tcc filename.c -run` I get:

```
VAL: 4
VAL: 6
VAL: 8
VAL: 10
VAL: 27092544
VAL: 1489483720
VAL: 0
END
```

With the last number always being zero and the other two extra values being different every time I run.

I figured out the solution which was adding `l1 -> next = NULL;` in the `newList` function and `l2 -> next = NULL;` in the `appendList` function.

But I was wondering why there was a difference in output. Is there a bug in the compiler or was I wrong for not initialising the pointer to `NULL` even though it works in most compilers?

Comment: Because without assigning `NULL` you are invoking the *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Using uninitialized variables is undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `return l2;
};

int main(){`  The stray semicolon `;` after the closing brace does not compile on a modern compiler

Comment: @user3629249: I've tried it on GCC, Clang and TCC and it compiles fine on all of them.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -std=gnu11`)  then fix the warnings

Comment: @user3629249: Thanks, that shows the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I figured out the solution which was adding `l1 -> next = NULL;` in the
>   `newList` function and `l2 -> next = NULL;` in the `appendList` function.
>
> But I was wondering why there was a difference in output. Is there a
>   bug in the compiler or was I wrong for not initialising the pointer to
>   `NULL` even though it works in most compilers?

You were wrong to access the pointer's value without having assigned it one or caused it to be explicitly or implicitly initialized (which are different from assigning a value).  Doing so produces undefined behavior.  That the program nevertheless happened to exhibit the behavior you expected under some circumstances is a possible and plausible result, but it does not validate the program.

Moreover, you are likely to find that your original approach *does not* work reliably with the other compilers you tested under more complex circumstances (but I can make only a probabilistic statement about that, because "undefined").

Comment: My mistake was assuming uninitialised pointers were null by default because most compilers gave the correct output. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AppTest-- making assumptions when programming in C is just asking for trouble, which may manifest when you least expect it. In C, if you don't _know_, you really need to consult the [Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html), or at least a reliable reference.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you debug a program the debugger initialize everything, but in production there is no initialization, so next values is not null

Initialize next variables.

Comment: Debugger is not initializing anything. It's just that the debugging environment might be different from the non-debugging one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. could be, but I saw 100ths times, an uninitialized variable value as 0 debugging and random value in execution, I supposed that it was de debugger because 0 is not a random or casual value, but probably you are right and it could be "cleaned" memory or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The function calloc() returns a pointer to a sequence of bytes that are initialized to zero; malloc(), by comparison, returns a pointer to a sequence of bytes that may or may not happen to initially contain zero.  On some platforms, those bytes will always contain zero after a malloc(); on others, at least some of them never will.  Generally, it's unpredictable which bytes will hold zero and which won't.

On most platforms, including nearly all that have been created in the last couple decades, clearing all of the bytes of a pointer object will set the pointer to NULL.  On platforms that document such behavior, using "calloc" rather than "malloc" to create space for a structure containing pointers would be a reliable way of initializing to NULL all pointers therein.  If one creates storage with "malloc" or "realloc" rather than "calloc", however, it will be necessary to either use "memset" to set all the bytes to zero, or else expressly set pointers contained therein to NULL.